# laravel project storing data in database does not work

Tags: php, database, laravel, storing-information

I have a laravel project that is using a mysql database with a few tables.Lets start by showing you all my files that are being used.My problem is that when I try to create the 'Conseillere' into the database, I get error:

```
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'date_anniversaire' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `conseilleres` () values ())'
```

Plus I dont know if what I did REALLY save it properly in the database. Basically, The conseillere model only has 2 date, but also have nom,prenom,adresse and adresse_courriel. Nom and Prenom are in another table called Personne.Adresse and ville are in another table named Adresse.Adresse_courriel is in another table called Courriel. Conseillere has all these attributes but they are referenced/contained in other tables/models.Conseillere model only contain date_anniversaire and date_entree column.Conseillere is a Personne. I am going to include some files that are needed, but im not sure if it would need more to help solve my issue.

First the usercontroller function that store the Conseillere into the database:

```
public function store(){

    $input = Input::all();
    $unepersonne = Personne::create([]);
    $uncourriel = new Courriel;
    $adresse = new Adresse;
    $conseillere = Conseillere::create([]);

    $uncourriel->adresse_courriel = $input['adresse_courriel'];
    $unepersonne->nom = $input['nom'];
    $unepersonne->prenom = $input['prenom'];

    $adresse->adresse = $input['adresse'];
    $adresse->ville = $input['ville'];

    //the following function are creating drop downs to input a date. for translation purpose, annee=year  mois=months and jour=day
    $conseillere->date_anniversaire = ConseillereController::construire_date($input['annee_anniversaire']-1, $input['mois_anniversaire']-1, $input['jour_anniversaire']-1);
    $conseillere->date_entree = ConseillereController::construire_date($input['annee_entree']-1, $input['mois_entree']-1, $input['jour_entree']-1);


    if ($unepersonne->save()){


    } else {

        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($conseillere->validationMessages());
    }




}
```

construire_date function:

```
    private function construire_date($annee, $mois, $jour)
{
    if (checkdate($mois, $jour, $annee)) {
        $dateTest = new DateTime;
        $dateTest->setDate($annee, $mois, $jour);
        return $dateTest->format('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        return "invalide";
    }
}
```

}

Conseillere model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Conseillere extends EloquentValidating {
protected $guarded = array('id');


public $timestamps = false;


public function conseillere() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Conseillere');
}



protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'prenom',
        'adresse',
        'ville',
        'adresse_courriel',
        'date_anniversaire',
        'date_entree'
    ];

/**
 * Validation
 */

public $validationMessages;

public function validationRules() {
    return [
            'date_anniversaire' => 'nullable|date',
            'date_entree' => 'nullable|date'
    ];
}
```

}

Personne model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Personne extends EloquentValidating
{

protected $table = 'personnes';


public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = [

    'nom', 
    'prenom',
];


public $validationMessages;

public function validationRules() {
    return
    [
            'personne' => 'required',
    ];
}


public function utilisateurs(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Utilisateur');
}



public function adresse() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Adresse');
}


public function carte_credits(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Carte_credit');
}

public function courriels(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Courriel');
}
```

}

Migrations of Conseillere:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('conseilleres', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->dateTime('date_anniversaire');
        $table->dateTime('date_entree');

        $table->integer('personne_id')
                        ->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('personne_id')
                        ->references('id')
                        ->on('personnes')
                        ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}
```

Migrations of Personne:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personnes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('prenom');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Ive been searching for a while and cant figure why the store function isnt working and not saving into the db.

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the line that is throwing the error you quote:

```
$conseillere = Conseillere::create([]);
```

[The `create` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) creates and saves a record immediately.  It accepts an array of field => value data, but you are passing in an empty array, so it is trying to insert a blank record into the DB.

Going by your code, I think you are trying to create a new Conseillere model instance, set attributes, and then save it.  If so, change that line to:

```
$conseillere = new Conseillere;
```

And then later, after you've set the required attributes:

```
$conseillere->date_entree = ...
$conseillere->save();
```

**UPDATE**

Note though that I think you are going to have additional problems as your migration shows that a record in `conseilleres` has a foreign key `personne_id`.  So maybe you are trying to create your `Personne`, and save it along with the associated `Conseillere`?  If yes, you need to make a few changes.

First, AFAICT your `Conseillere` <-> `Personne` relationship is not defined correctly.  Your `Conseillere` model shows:

```
public function conseillere() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Conseillere');
}
```

But why would `Conseillere` be related to itself?  Shouldn't that be `personne`?

```
public function personne() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Personne');
}
```

You will also need to add the inverse relation on your `Personne` model, I do not see it in your code.

Next, you need to save both the `Personne`, and the related `Conseillere`.  You can do that [as described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method):

```
// As above, change your create call to a simple 'new'
$conseillere = new Conseillere;

// ... rest of your code ...
$conseillere->date_entree = ...

// Now save the updated personne.  This only works bcs
// when you did $unepersonne = Personne::create([]) it created a 
// blank record in the DB with an id, basically you are doing an 
// update of an existing record here.
$unepersonne->save();

// Now save the related model.
$unepersonne->conseillere()->save($conseillere);
```

Comment: This is the way I did it before,however this method doesnt seem the create the id increment.It just create it when I save wich cause problem.By doing $conseillere = Conseillere::create([]); it assign an ID to it. Also there was a typo mistake beside the save statement, I edited it in the question. When doing $conseillere = new Conseillere; I get no error, but nothing is created in the database, wich is my second problem and I dont understand why.

Comment: It did not create a record bcs you never saved it to the DB. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you said in your update, but now I am getting error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::conseillere()

Comment: Yes I tried what is currently in your update and im getting that error

Comment: Did you add the `conseillere` relation in your `Personne` model?

Comment: I added  public function conseillere() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Conseillere');
 }
in the Personne model(is that correct?). After doing that, I am getting error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Comment: Updated the line like you said, still getting  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Comment: OK, which line? There are 2x `save()`s.  You can debug too you know :-)

Comment: I am kinda new to laravel, I updated the save line to $unepersonne->conseillere()->save($conseillere); like you said and I keep getting that error :( My code is exactly like your update right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160558/discussion-between-dont-panic-and-martin-b).

Answer (score 0):

If understand Your problem clearly or if you are using laravel 5.4 or 5.5... You need to open **config/database.php** here you need to change the value of **strict** to false. Something Like this:-

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,  // replace true to false here
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why is this required?

Comment: @Don'tPanic beacuse i have the same issue in laravel 5.4 grater version doesn't have a default value  issue so i resolve in that way

Comment: I don't understand what that means ... this might be the answer, but you will greatly increase the quality of your answer if you explain why the change you suggest will help, and exactly what it does.  Code-only answers are generally considered low quality here on SO - explain *why*, not just what.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for your suggestion :) if you will define strict to flase then everything will be run fine if you are using true it throw error whenever you are saving nothing on  that column